# Add Image into Tooltip in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, coffeescript, tooltip

I'm trying to include an image in my Tooltip:

My Link:

```
<%= link_to "#", class: "tag-tooltip",
                    'data-placement' => 'right',
                    :rel => "tooltip" %>
```

My Js(coffee):

```
$(document).on "ready page:change", ->
  $(document).ready ->
  $(".tag-tooltip").tooltip({ title: "whatsup", content: "<img src=\"http://icdn.pro/images/fr/a/v/avatar-barbe-brun-homme-utilisateur-icone-9665-128.png\" />", html: true})
```

But only the Text is appearing.. What am i Missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `template` in place of `content` like follows:

```
$(document).on "ready page:change", ->
  $(document).ready ->
    $(".tag-tooltip").tooltip({ title: "whatsup", template: "<img src=\"http://icdn.pro/images/fr/a/v/avatar-barbe-brun-homme-utilisateur-icone-9665-128.png\" />", html: true})
```

**Update:**

Based on the [gem code](https://github.com/brandonhilkert/bootstrap-tooltip-rails/blob/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/bootstrap-tooltip.js), it appears that the content of the tooltip is actually the `title`.  So you could also do:

```
$(document).on "ready page:change", ->
  $(document).ready ->
    $(".tag-tooltip").tooltip({ title: "<img src=\"http://icdn.pro/images/fr/a/v/avatar-barbe-brun-homme-utilisateur-icone-9665-128.png\" />", html: true})
```

Comment: Hey Vino, thanks a lot. Including it in the title worked just fine :)

Comment: hello! Can you help me with that?
I dont understand how?